# What kind of SSL cert do I need here

Tags: https, security-certificate, geolocation

I am in the process of setting up a distributed server setup with each server claiming to use the same domain name. I will be using a geolocation DNS service (there are now several cheap providers here: edgedirector and zerigo spring to mind) to ensure that visitors to the hosted site are directed to their "geographically closest" server.

Nothing complicated so far.  The one thing I am not too clear about - will I be able to get away with using the same simple single domain SSL certificate on each server or will I have to get a wildcard cert even though I am not setting up sub-domains?  The difference in price between the two kinds of cert is not inconsiderable.  I would much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a single-domain certificate to as many servers as you wish.  Wildcard certificates are only if you want to use multiple subdomains (hosts) on a domain.

The geographic location of the servers does not matter.